# Parse Javascript XML Subcategories

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm at whits end. I have an XML document that contains the following:

```
<root>
  <parentCategory cat="MainCategory1">

  </parentCategory>
  <parentCategory cat="MainCategory2">
     <subcategory subs="subcategory1">
       <title></title>
       <author></author>
     </subcategory>
     <subcategory subs="subcategory2">
        <book>
           <title>1</title>
           <author>2</author>
        </book>
          <book>
           <title>2</title>
           <author>2</author>
        </book>
     </subcategory>
  </parentCategory>
</root>
```

I'm trying to parse an XML document using the following:
1) If Parent Category cat = MainCategory2 and subcategory subs = subcategory2 then
2) Iterate through all books in that subcategory only

I have tried doing this with jQuery, but I is doing the following:
1) Searching through the XML document for every subcategory and then counting them up.  If I have 10 Subcategories the number of the loop is 10.
2) Its then displaying the books in subcategory2 10 times.  Book1, Book2, Book1, Book2 ...  10 times.  I can't make it show just once.

I thought I would do it in JavaScript, but I can't break down the childnodes.

Here is my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "xml/books.xml",
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(data) {
                var xml_node = $('books',data);
                var itemcount = $(xml_node).find('books[category] subcategory[itemcount]').text();
                $(xml_node).find('subcategory[subs="'+ subcategory +'"] > icd10').each(function(ind, subs) {

                    var title = $(subs).find('title').text();
                    var author = $(subs).find('author').text();
                    var description = $(subs).find('description').html();


                    console.log(itemcount);

                });

            } // End Success
        }); //End AJAX
```

or JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(xml,subcategory) {
          var i;
          var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
          var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cat");
          var newSubs = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("subcategory");
          for (i=0;i<newSubs.length;i++)
            {
                var subs = newSubs[i].getAttribute('subs');
                if(subs === subcategory){
                    var c = xmlDoc.nodeType;
                    console.log(c);
                }
            } 

          /* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table; */
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your code and your xml doesn't seem to match, for instance there are no `books` tags or `cat` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If `parentCategory` cat = `MainCategory2` and `subcategory` subs = `subcategory2` then
> 2. Iterate through all books in that subcategory only

```
var selector = "parentCategory[cat='MainCategory2'] > subcategory[subs='subcategory2'] > book";
$(xml).find(selector).each(function () {
    // do something with each book
});
```

---

FWIW, DOM-API based solution:

```
var books = xml.getElementsByTagName('book'),
    b, parent, grandparent;

for (b = 0; b < books.length; b++) {
    parent = books[b].parentNode;
    grandparent = parent.parentNode;
    if (
        parent.nodeName == "subcategory" && 
        grandparent.nodeName == "parentCategory" &&
        parent.getAttribute("subs") == "subcategory2" && 
        grandparent.getAttribute("cat") == "MainCategory2"
    ) {
        // do something with each book
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use this code for again, but Its iterating 5 time still.  http://52.22.109.31/icd10/www/chapters.html

If you choose the 3rd option and and then anyone of the dropdown options you can see how its running through the loop 5 times.

Comment: If I could post the updated function I would, but I did get everything to show using and edit of your code, but Its still iterating 5 times.

Comment: @user Look, I won't debug your stuff for you. Both my solutions work for the problem you gave in your question as you have asked it; I've tested them. If they do not work for your real situation then you might have asked the wrong question. Open the developer tools of your browser, set a few breakpoints at key places in your code and step through line by line and you will find out where the unexpected duplication comes from.